# Uploading image to S3 bucket

Tags: android, amazon-s3

How to upload an image to Amazon s3 bucket in android?.I am having secret key and access key for uploading but still not able to do.Here is my code

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress("Sleeping..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
            String date = (DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date()).toString());
            String ACCESS_KEY = "",
                    SECRET_KEY = "",
                    MY_BUCKET = "retailappimages",
                    OBJECT_KEY = unique_id+"-"+date;
            AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
            AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
            java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "60");
            s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1));
            s3.setEndpoint("https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/");

            Log.i("path", myUri.getPath());


            TransferManager tx = new TransferManager(credentials);
            myUpload = tx.upload(MY_BUCKET, OBJECT_KEY, new java.io.File(getBitmapUri(img_product).getPath()));


            return resp;
        }
```

Comment: You should provide more information. Which libraries did you try?  And what is getting wrong.

Comment: @CyberAleks...can you tell me how to do this...if you know..because I am new to android

Comment: You need the libraries from Amazon. Read developer docs for s3.

Comment: do u have any successful code with you just provide..

Comment: @Tinto Mathew: see my answer  which is working properly in my current project.

Comment: @Tinto Mathew: see my updated answer.

Comment: Post your code what ever you did till the date with Complete requirement .

Comment: I am getting the following error.........................................I/AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0x55a77c5fe0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample code Put your won keys & bucket_name in code:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ResponseHeaderOverrides;
import com.worldofmoms.networklib.R;
import com.worldofmoms.networklib.listeners.IRequestListener;
import com.worldofmoms.networklib.utils.helpers.LocalLog;
import java.io.File;

public class UploadImageTask  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private IRequestListener<Object> mListener;
    private String mRequestTag;
    Context mContext;

    public UploadImageTask(Context context,String requestTag, IRequestListener<Object> listener)
    {
        mContext=context;
        mRequestTag=requestTag;
        this.mListener=listener;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, null, "", true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loaders_progress_dialog);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String path = params[0];
        return sendImageToAmazonS3Server(path);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        if (dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        this.mListener.onRequestSuccess(mRequestTag, sResponse);
    }

    private String sendImageToAmazonS3Server(String Filepath){
        //String MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
        String MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "Put Access key";

        //String MY_SECRET_KEY 
        String MY_SECRET_KEY = "Put SECRET_KEY ";


        //String MY_PICTURE_BUCKET 
        String MY_PICTURE_BUCKET = "bucketName";
        //String MY_PICTURE_BUCKET = "wom-profilepics-test";

        String rootUpload = Filepath;
        File file = new File(rootUpload);
        if (file.exists()) {
            String fileExtension="jpg";

            String imageNAME = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            String fileNameToUpload = imageNAME+"."+fileExtension;
            fileNameToUpload=fileNameToUpload.trim();
            try {
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID, MY_SECRET_KEY));
            // create bucket
            //s3Client.createBucket(MY_PICTURE_BUCKET);
            InputStream input = new URL("https://hi.co/bundles/hitomain/images/hi_big.png?v=1448090952").openStream();
            ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(MY_PICTURE_BUCKET,fileNameToUpload,input,objectMetadata);
            por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            PutObjectResult result = s3Client.putObject(por);

                 LocalLog.d("PATH", "" + fileNameToUpload);

                /*LocalLog.d("putting Object result ",""+ result.getETag()
                        //result.
                        + " MD5 " + result.getContentMd5());*/

                ResponseHeaderOverrides override = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
                override.setContentType("image/jpeg");

                /*GeneratePresignedUrlRequest urlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest( MY_PICTURE_BUCKET,imageNAME );
                urlRequest.setExpiration( new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000));  // Added an hour's worth of milliseconds to the current time.
                urlRequest.setResponseHeaders(override);
                URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl( urlRequest );*/
                //LocalLog.d(" S3 SERVER IMAGE PATH = ",""+url.toString());
                String filePathOnServer = "http://"+MY_PICTURE_BUCKET+".s3.amazonaws.com/"+fileNameToUpload;
                LocalLog.d(" S3 SERVER IMAGE PATH = ",""+filePathOnServer);
                return filePathOnServer;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LocalLog.printStackTrace(e);
                return "";
            }
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can anyone help me to do this.I need to upload image to s3 on a button click.I go through the documentation but I don't feel it's useful for a developer in the learning face.Can any one provide a successful code for this scenario???

Comment: http://www.javaroots.com/2013/05/how-to-upload-and-download-images-in.html

Comment: Check now I have updated code as put image from URL to S3 Server.

Comment: Changed following 3 lines:  InputStream input = new URL("https://hi.co/bundles/hitomain/images/hi_big.png?v=1448090952").openStream();
            ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(MY_PICTURE_BUCKET,fileNameToUpload,input,objectMetadata);

Comment: @suhas..I think my case is different